# nested sections

Tags: sections, slug, nested, uri

how can i achieve the following result?

i have a structured section called products like `/hardware/apple/iPhone` which gets the template `/templates/productpage.twig`

now i need need to  load a different structured section called content on `/apple/iphone/tricks`

i worked one with the sulu cms. there you could create nested pages but could change the site type on every site.
for my undestanding i cant nest different section types. correct me if i am wrong.

so my plan was to create a section of type channel an set the {slug} to /apple/iphone/tricks but the slashes get removed. then i tried do get the uri from a field so i set thet uri to {entry.text} but that gave me of course template not found.

did i miss something or is my result not working with "the craft way"?

best nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be referring to what Craft term an "Entry Type". A section can have a number of entry types, each of which can have their own set of fields and template.

So you have a section called "Products", and two entry types of something like "Product Page" and "Tricks Page". When authoring your content, you assign the relevant entry type to your entry (page). If that sounds like it's what you're trying to achieve, there's a [KB guide here](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/entry-type-templates).

You have less control over URLs though, since they are determined by the section rather than the entry type.

Comment: dude you are awesome. believe it or not i never checked that i can have multiple entry types. i just never read it right. 2 years with craft and always struggled with these type of url stuff and now it just clicked. thanks a lot!!!